# G acts faithfully on X, N is a minimal normal subgroup of G, N abelian, acts transitively. Prove G acts primitively

Tags: group-theory

I want to ask for a hint or solution to this problem:

G acts faithfully on X, N is a minimal normal subgroup of G, N abelian, and acts transitively on X. Prove G acts primitively

Comment: Try proving each of the following: (1) N acts regularly so WLOG N=X. (2) N has a complement H in G. (3) H acts irreducibly on N. (4) Anything bigger than H contains all of N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that normal subgroups preserve partitions.

Show that in this situation only the trivial partitions can be preserved.